# Long-form notation of a string assignment

Tags: c, string

I was wondering what the equivalent "long-form" way of creating a string would be. My first thought as as follows:

```
char *string = "Hello";
```

is short-form for:

```
char _string[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
char *string = &_string[0];
```

Is this the closest approximation of what a string assignment actually does? When was the short-form notation introduced?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what your initialization is equivalent to (except that `_string` has no name at all).  You could make it even closer by declaring `_string` as `const`.

Comment: As far as I know, though, what you're calling the "short form" has been part of C since the very beginning.

Comment: That’s not how it is. The short form actually places the string in a read-only place at compile time. And that is not equal to the example you showed.

Comment: `char *string = "Hello";` is actually the short form of `char *string = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};`

Comment: @Jabberwocky Except that that form of nameless array initializer was never part of K&R C.

Comment: @Fredrik: Whether the array of a string literal is placed in read-only memory is implementation-dependent. It is not required by the C standard.

Comment: @Eric that may be, the important part is that the string is a compile time literal and ’lives’ during the entire execution time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are you sure about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778300/long-form-notation-of-a-string-assignment#comment101991684_57778300)?

Comment: I clicked on it and it went to the right comment which is yours BTW. Your answer seems correct to me @EricPostpischil

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: Okay. Whether a browser is able to scroll to the comment may depend on window size and other factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals have three properties your proposed long form does not:

- They have static storage duration, meaning they exist (in the computing model used by the C standard) for the duration of program execution.
- The behavior of attempting to modify them is not defined by the C standard, even though they do not have a `const` qualifier (which is a legacy due to the historical development of C).
- When the compiler sees identical string literals, it is allowed to consolidate them. This could be visible to the program by comparing addresses. The compiler is also allowed to consolidate "abcdef" and "def" to "abcdef", since the latter is a subsequence of the former.

So a closer equivalent would be:

```
static const char _string[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
char *string = (char *) _string;
```

Thus, `string` does not have the `const` qualifier, and it does point to an array of static storage duration for which attempting to modify it is not defined by the C standard.

I do not believe there is a good way to replicate the third property, so `_string` will be a distinct object even if the same data appears elsewhere in the program.

String literals have existed in C since at least 1978, as they appear in the first edition of *The C Programming Language* by Kernighan and Ritchie, which calls them string constants.

Comment: thanks for this explanation. Why wouldn't the second line just be `char *string = &_string[0]` ? Or is `(char *) _string` equivalent to `&_string[0]` ?

Comment: @Shared: When used in this way, `_string` is equivalent to `&_string[0]`. The problem is `&_string[0]` has type `const char *`, and assigning a `const char *` to `char *` is a constraint violation—you cannot implicitly remove `const`. However, you can explicitly remove it with a cast, hence the `(char *)`.